# How can I align the textview in cardview for recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am creating a `RecyclerView` with the data from the database. And for making a row I created a resource file as `row_layout.xml` and it has two `TextView`. I want it in a `CardView` but while creating the `TextView` created cant be aligned.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/sl"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="9dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the `Constraints` the right way instead of suppressing the warning by adding `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"`.

1. When aligned to Left:

   [image]

   ```
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="12dp">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/sl"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="1"
               android:textColor="#000"
               android:textSize="40sp"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/nameTV"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/nameTV"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Name"
               android:textColor="#000"
               android:textSize="40sp"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/sl"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
   ```
2. When aligned to both Left and Right of the parent which makes them equally distanced:

   [image]

   ```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp">

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/nameTV"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/sl"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
   ```
3. When aligned to both Left and Right of the parent but with horizontal chain style packed, just like this spread inside will spread them at each ends :

   [image]

   ```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp">

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/nameTV"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/sl"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
   ```
4. When aligned to Right of the parent:

   [image]

   ```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp">

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/nameTV"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/sl"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
   ```

Just like these, play with Start/Left and End/Right Margins and layout width and height and create custom layouts as you want. I've used Left and Right instead of Start and End, but if you want to make your application support RTL(Right to Left) layouts, use only Start/End constraints and margins.
Also, if you set both left and right constraints of a view and then set the width as `0dp`, it will the available space completely. `ConstraintLayout` is very advanced, have a look in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/s1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/s2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/s2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/s1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Hope this helps... Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: Would help to perhaps point out what changes were made to align it

Comment: @ADARSHAK Edited Code Please check :)